# Norm of a matrix with inf

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How can I prove that the norm of a matrix can be represented as the inf, i.e, $$N(A) = \sup_{x \in\mathbb R^n, \|x\| \leq 1} N(Ax)$$
Then $$N(A)=\{c \leq 0 : \forall x \in\mathbb R^n , N(Ax) \leq cN(x) \}$$

Some help please I do not how to attack this problem, did I need to prove that the inf is reached ?

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

1. $N(A)= \inf \{c \ge 0 : \forall x \in R^n , N(Ax) \leq cN(x) \}$
2. $\{x \in R^n: ||x|| \le 1\}$ is compact.